# In iOS, is there a simple way to visually draw all ViewBounds on screen?

Tags: ios, xcode

On Android, there is a developer function where you can turn on ViewBounds so that every view being drawn to the screen has a colorful rectangle around it. It's really handy for troubleshooting things.

Is there an easy to do this in iOS? I'd like to see the view bounds of every element on my screen. I know it's messy, but it's super helpful.

[image]

Comment: Debug > View debugging > show view frames

Comment: That's also awesome. I'm developing a custom keyboard. I don't think that will work on an extension (it's not working for me right now). Any idea if I'm just doing something wrong? thanks

Comment: The pic above is actually a MotoX Developer Edition tool. I don't know if it's available on all Android devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is very usefull button introduced in XCode 6

[image]